# Convert a string of list(tuple(int) into a proper list of tuple of int

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

In a csv file Ive saved a list(tuple(int, int))
but when reading the line I get a string
but how can I convert this "[(56, 365), (62, 801)]" to [(56, 365), (62, 801)]

Comment: if you wrote it out by converting your raw Python data to string like `strval = str([(56, 365), (62, 801)])` then you can read it back with `eval(strval)`.

Comment: Frame challenge: Having the string representation of a structured Python value as a column in a CSV file is a horrible data format. If at all possible, write the whole thing as, for example, JSON instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
import ast

new_list = ast.literal_eval(your_list)
```

This should solve your problem!

Answer (score 0):

Another way of solving this problem without using libraries is to manipulate the string to give you what you want. Here's some code where I took in the string, parsed it down to integers and built a new array for the desired format for the output. There might be a easier way to manipulate the string but here's a working first shot.

```
string_array = "[(56, 365), (62, 801)]"

no_spaces = string_array.replace(" ","")
without_Lbrackets = no_spaces.replace("[","")
without_brackets = without_Lbrackets.replace("]","")
without_Lparantheses = without_brackets.replace("(","")
without_parantheses = without_Lparantheses.replace(")","")

strarray = without_parantheses.split(",")

intarray = [(int(strarray[0]),int(strarray[1])),(int(strarray[2]),int(strarray[3]))]
print(intarray)
```

Answer (score -1):

An easy but not very safe way would be to use `eval(line)` with `line` being the string to be parsed.